# Build UIAlertController recursively and present it

Tags: ios, recursion, uialertcontroller

I want to present a `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` one after another. To do this, I must present the next `UIAlertController` inside of the handler of my `UIAlertAction`.

```
UIAlertController *A = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert A" message:@"My Alert A" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* A_Action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"A Action" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    UIAlertController *B = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert B" message:@"My Alert B" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction* B_Action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"B Action" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        UIAlertController *C = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert C" message:@"My Alert C" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

        UIAlertAction* C_Action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"C Action" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            //keep going for N number of UIAlertControllers that I want to present
        }];

        [alert addAction:C_Action];

        [self presentViewController:C animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    [alert addAction:B_Action];

    [self presentViewController:B animated:YES completion:nil];
}];

[alert addAction:A_Action];
[self presentViewController:A animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there a way to do this recursively?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one method that shows one alert controller. In the action handler you simply call the same method to show the next alert.

The trick is knowing when to stop and dealing with each alert's message and buttons. The following code assumes you have some instance variables that contains a way to access the messages and titles of each alert based on its number. It also assume each alert has one button - the one that goes to the next alert.

Something along the lines of this:

```
- (void)showNextAlert:(NSInteger)count {
    NSString *message = ... // determine the message for alert n
    NSString *title = ... // determine the title for alert n
    NSString *button = ... // determine the title of the action for alert n

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:button style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        // Process the button for alert n

        // Check to see if another alert should be shown or not
        if (count < self.maxAlerts) {
            // Give the current alert a chance to dismiss
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [self showNextAlert:count + 1];
            });
        }
    }];

    [alert addAction:action];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Elsewhere, show the 1st alert
[self showNextAlert:0];
```

This code is not tested but should give you the general idea.